# Gstreamer doesn't work (shows the same image everytime)

Tags: pi-3, video, gstreamer

I'm trying to connect an IP Camera to my gtk+ application. In order to accomplish this I'm using `gstreamer` with `videooverlay` like in this [tutorial](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/tutorials/basic/toolkit-integration.html).

The problem I have is the video doesn't run and shows the same image every time.
To verify the code was working, I tried running `gstreamer` directly from the command line, but I still get the same problem. You can see [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hx2RY9tVetY) (video is to slow because of recorder too).

Any ideas why the video doesn't run?

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h5iSuXc0BIw) you can see `gstreamer` running on my machine.

And [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_jjqlr5vtyM) you can see the commands that I'm using to reproduce the stream, as well as the message that I get from my Raspberry Pi.