# Gstreamer compile gives "undefined reference" error

Tags: gstreamer

I'm trying to compile a newest version of gstreamer in raspberry pi. First of all a tried to download from [here](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/modules/). i Run `sudo ./configure`and next `sudo make`and i get the following error:

`/usr/local/lib/libgtk-3.so: undefined reference 'pango_fc_font_map_config_changed'`

I tried compile with [this](https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/gstreamer-openmax/2013-March/000724.html) method but give the same error.~

I'm tring to compile a newest version because don't works ([you can see here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/68175/gstreamer-doesnt-work-shows-the-same-image-everytime)) problem with the oldest..